# How to find a song by name and remove it from playlist

Tags: c#, playlist, windows-media-player, wmplib

Basically I'm making a jukebox and I have a big problem with the WMPLib library.
I am trying to remove an item from the playlist , but the problem is that I can't find any way to get the index or the actual media by name. 

I 
was thinking of making a replica array of the playlist , but that is just stupidly more work then what I should put into a simple task like that.

```
 private void queue_listbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (queue_listbox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            wplayer.currentPlaylist.removeItem('Insert code here');
            music_listbox.Items.Add(queue_listbox.SelectedItem);
            queue_listbox.Items.Remove(queue_listbox.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh yeah and just to elaborate I have the path of the media file and just the file name , but there is no command that lets you search through a playlist.

Comment: You don't need the index. You should be able to use [getByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564784(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the item *itself*, then pass the item to [removeItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564850(v=vs.85).aspx) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` like so:

```
// The string will be used as the name to find the song. 
// I don't know what type you are using for the song, 
// so I'm just using the madeup type "Song"
Dictionary<string, Song> songs = new Dictionary<string, Song>();
```

And then you can remove it by doing (pseudo code)

```
// Removes "Look at this Photograph" from the songs Dictionary
songs["Look at this Photograph - Nickleback"].Remove();
```

Dictionaries are pretty much lists, which are pretty much arrays, except, instead of passing a number as an indexer (`songs[5]` gets the 6th song) you can pass whatever type `TKey` is (`songs["Look at this Photograph"]` gets the song that is paired with that string).

I don't know if you made that `Listbox` class or if it's built by Microsoft. If it is built, then `Items` is can't be made a dictionary if it's already an array, in which case, you'll need to get more creative. You might have to basically recreate `Listbox` just to have the `Dictionary` or some clever workaround.

You could do something like making a `ListboxManager` which would hold a `Dictionary<Listbox, Dictionary<string, Song>>` and use an extension method called `GetItems(this Listbox listbox) => ListBoxManager.Listboxes[listbox];` which would probably work.